# How can I build a LINQ query with dynamic OR statements?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

The following code:

```
var dynamicQuery = from a in _context.Users select a;

string[] args = new string[] { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
foreach (string word in args)
{
    dynamicQuery = dynamicQuery.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(word));
}

return dynamicQuery.ToList();
```

Will allow me to create a LINQ query with a dynamic list of **AND** expressions.

But suppose I wanted to do the same, only with a dynamic list of **OR** expressions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to loop at all:

```
return _context.Users.Where(x => args.Any(word => x.Name.Contains(word)));
```

EDIT: More generally, you can use:

```
Func<User, bool> predicate = user => false;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var predicateCopy = predicate;
    predicate = user => predicateCopy(user) || someOtherCondition;
}
return query.Where(predicate);
```

This will end up with quite deep stacks (with one delegate calling another calling another etc). Where the specific situation allows you to use `Any`, that would usually be a better approach.

I would expect `Any` to work in most situations where you've got a collection of items to potentially match against... the non-`Any` approach is approprate for "in some situations, anyone over 18 is fine... in some situations anyone with a last name beginning with "G" is appropriate, etc.

Comment: While this does answers this specific scenario, is there a more general approach?

Comment: That was my initial thought, but it  gives me a stackoverflow exception as if predicate calls itself instead of the previous Func

Comment: @sternr: Um, yes - hang on, fixing... done. Now it'll capture a different variable for each iteration of the loop. Doh.

Comment: Ummm, this doesn't give an exception, but it doesnt work - it ignores someOtherCondition

Comment: @stern: It shouldn't... can you produce a short but complete example which shows that?

Comment: Is there not a problem with the general approach in the sense that it does not translate to SQL? `IQueryable.Where` accepts `Expression<Func<>>`, `IEnumerable.Where` accepts `Func<>`, so passing a `Func<>` predicate results in fetching the entire table on the client and filtering it with the predicate instead of translating it to SQL, and declaring the `predicate` as `Expression<Func<>>` also does not work because then it can't be called like `predicateCopy(user)`.

Comment: @GSerg: Yes, this answer is only an answer to the question being asked, which was using LINQ to Objects. If you want a Queryable-based solution, you'd need a slightly different approach. (There's a utility class somewhere that does this, but I can't remember what it's called now...)