# Need multiple where conditions to a query with OR operator

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a requirement to add multiple where conditions with or operator out of which one where condition will have to check if the db column has any of the item in a list provided. Please consider the query below

```
var res= from table1 in context.table1
         join table2 in context.table2
         on table1.id equals table2.id
         where table1.name=="res1" || table1.description=="desc"
         || table1.name.any(res=>FreeText.Contains(res))
         select table1
```

this query is leading the compiler to run query multiple times and I am not getting required result. My end goal is to achieve the following sql query

```
select * from table1 join table2 on table1.id ==table2.id 
  where table1.name=="res1" || table1.description=="desc" || table1.name like "%item1%" ||table1.name like "%item2% ......"
```

the like statements should be dynamically added based on the items in the list.

Comment: This sounds more like client evaluation (non SQL translatable construct) issue rather than OR operator. What is `FreeText` in your query?

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: FreeText is a list which contains string which needs to be checked in the where condition as like

Comment: `table1.name.Any(res=>FreeText.Contains(res))` is backwards. That `Any` is from `string`'s `IEnumerable<char>`. You wanted `FreeText.Contains(table1.name)`

Comment: But if `table1.name` is `string`, then `res` must be `char`, right? If `FreeText` is `string[]`, the code should not even compile.

Comment: check this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7180331/1745913

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
var res= from table1 in context.table1
         join table2 in context.table2
         on table1.id equals table2.id
         where table1.name=="res1" || table1.description=="desc"
         || FreeText.Any(p => table1.name.Contains(p, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
         select table1
```

Comment: How would a string contain a list of strings in it? This doesn't even compile

Comment: FreeText is a list of string. Each element in the list should be compared to the name column using contains

Comment: check the edited answer. I've added StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase to ignore case.